# Using span tags in meta description & title, for dual languages

Tags: html, multilingual, meta-tags, right-to-left, html-title

I use both Persian characters and English in `meta`-`description` & `title` tag and I'm wondering if I can use `span` tags?

```
<meta name="description" content="The movie is Italy Italy - <span dir='rtl'>فیلم جدید</span>">

<title>The movie is Italy Italy - <span dir='rtl'>فیلم جدید</span></title>
```

The `span` tags define the direction e.g. `<span dir='rtl'></span>` for Persian characters.

Comment: See also on Webmasters SE: [How can I use dual language metadata?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/108390/17633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include elements inside attribute values.

The start-of-element special character `<` does not have its usual special meaning there and is treated as a literal less-than symbol.

The `<title>` element may not contain child elements either.